# Dúvidas sobre diagramas de atividade

Tags: diagrama

O diagrama de atividade ele descreve uma única atividade do sistema ou ele específica as diversas atividades do sistema?

Pode-se existir mais de um início no diagrama de atividade? Ex: Inicia uma atividade com um usuário comum mas também inicia uma atividade com um usuário especial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O diagrama de atividade descreve a sequência de atividades que envolve um software, mostrando desde as ações do usuário até a finalização de funções do software.

[image: Diagrama de atividade de uma locadora no qual o software de registro de locações funciona]

No exemplo acima eu descrevo um simples diagrama de atividade de uma locadora que utiliza um software de registro de locações, no qual acompanho desde a ação de um ator solicitar a locação, prosseguindo com as etapas que descrevem superficialmente as funções do software com pontos de decisões geralmente referidos ao ator.

Então resumindo, o diagrama de atividade descreve toda a funcionalidade do software descrevendo as atividades que levam até sua execução e até a finalização da sua execução. (No exemplo acima "Solicitar alocação" não é referente ao software em si, e sim aos funcionários da locadora, geralmente junto com o diagrama de atividade se acompanha uma tabela descrevendo melhor cada funcionalidade sua.

Answer (score 0):

O diagrama de atividades pode ter mais de um início e mais de um final. Ele descreve o fluxo de execução de uma atividade especifica do sistema, podendo abranger outra atividade desde que essa segunda atividade seja necessária para a execução da primeira.

Answer (score -2):

O diagrama de atividades representa o fluxo de uma atividade para outra, é um diagrama de fluxo.

De acordo com meus conhecimentos não é possível ter mais de um início, o que pode haver é dois fluxos um espera do outro para iniciar, porém não podem iniciar paralelamente.